# Testing two activities simultaneously with Espresso

Tags: android, testing, integration-testing, android-espresso

I am writing an instrumentation test for an assignment for an Android course. I'd like to be able to check that, for example, a `TextView` is correctly positioned on the screen. To do this, I want to compare the position of the `TextView` to the position of a similar `TextView` in a reference implementation; something like this:

```java
onView(withId(R.id.text_view))
    .check(isBottomAlignedWith(onView(withId(R.id.text_view_solution))
```

The issue I'm running into is that `R.id.text_view` and `R.id.text_view_solution` exist in separate activities. I create two activity rules, one for the assignment solution and one for student submission:

```java
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivity> mSubmission = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivity.class);
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<MainActivitySolution> mSolution = new ActivityTestRule<>(MainActivitySolution.class);
```

Previously, I've been simply getting the activities associated with the above rules and traversing the hierarchy myself to check, but it would be nice to be able to use convenience methods like `isBottomAlignedWith`. Additionally, I wanted to switch to Espresso as it's the only way I can find to test in landscape (something I'll also need to do).

However, for some reason, `onView` will only search the most recently created activity. So I can find views in `MainActivitySolution` but not in `MainActivity`. Is there a way do allow Espresso to search both activities for views?

Comment: AFAIK, you can have only one activity launched at any given time. So the answer is no you can't do this with activities. Have you tried fragments?

Comment: @VenomVendor Are you referring to Espresso or `AndroidJUnit4`? Because I've had no problem having two `ActivityTestRule`s as long as I test them by accessing the activity directly with `ActivityTestRule#getActivity`.

Comment: @VenomVendor I thought of fragments, but it would really complicate this assignment (which is the first assignment, so I want to make it as simple as possible). In reality, the activity that I'm testing is just a bottom tab bar wrapper which displays one of four views depending on which tab is selected. If there were a way to test a view directly, that would solve my issue however the only way I can see to do this ([here](https://github.com/novoda/espresso-support)) wraps the view in an activity.